# Foundation margin between columns not working

Tags: html, css, sass, zurb-foundation

First of all, I know it's a repeated question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22161532/zurb-foundation-margin-between-columns) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30318275/zurb-foundation-margin-between-2-columns)), but the solution has not worked for me.

This is my issue: I have a web page with the following structure:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-1 columns">...</div>
    <div class="small-8 columns">...</div>
    <div class="small-3 columns">...</div>
</div>
```

Inside my 8-column I have a Panel container, and inside it:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-1 columns">COLOR</div>
    <div class="small-2 columns">TITLE</div>
    <div class="small-1 columns">NAME</div>
    <div class="small-2 columns">SURNAME</div>
    <div class="small-2 columns">ADDRESS</div>
    <div class="small-2 columns">POSTAL CODE</div>
    <div class="small-2 columns">SUMMARY</div>
</div>
```

This is the content:
[image]

I would like each column with a gap separator. But, if I try to add this gap (with margin property):

[image]

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe add a span inside your div and apply margin on the span instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Foundation creates gap (aka gutter) with a combination of left and right padding and percentage width on .columns. Take a look at this from foundation.css:

```
.column, .columns {
    padding-left: 0.625rem;
    padding-right: 0.625rem;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.small-1 { width: 8.33333%; }
.small-2 { width: 16.66667%; }
...
```

By adding margin to the columns, you disrupt the widths and make .row > 100% which is why it's breaking. As a general rule, I recommend not ever adding margin to .columns as it will break the grid.

You have a few options:

1 - Collapse the row and add your own padding with additional classes inside the children columns

```
<div class="row collapse">
    <div class="small-1 columns"><div class="inner">COLOR</div></div>
    <div class="small-2 columns"><div class="inner">TITLE</div></div>
    <div class="small-1 columns"><div class="inner">NAME</div></div>
    <div class="small-2 columns"><div class="inner">SURNAME</div></div>
    <div class="small-2 columns"><div class="inner">ADDRESS</div></div>
    <div class="small-2 columns"><div class="inner">POSTAL CODE</div></div>
    <div class="small-2 columns"><div class="inner">SUMMARY</div></div>
</div>

.inner {background:#666; margin:0 5px; padding:5px;}
```

2 - It looks like you're trying to create a chart of sorts. There is no shame in using an actual HTML table for tabular data (that's what it's for). Foundation's default styling of tables is actually quite nice.